Why is a domain not expired or available for purchase?
My questions is about a .in tld (Indian country domain)
Updated Date: 2024-11-01T11:03:04Z Creation Date: 2022-11-01T10:05:27Z Registry Expiry Date: 2024-11-01T10:05:27Z Registrar: Endurance Digital Domain Technology Private Limited

I think it expires after 45 days but why not yet expired. Is the registry expiry date is wrong or has it auto-renewed?
